# next js with redux and reselect

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, reselect

I am having a problem that when I use reselect with next.js and redux the component won't re render when redux state has been changed by the reducer.

In the container I have a memoized selector function but the selector is called before the container and container is not re rendered after the CATEGORIES_LOADING_SUCCEEDED action.

When I do not memoize the selector it works but that would re render the menu every time something in the state changed.

Full code is [here](https://github.com/harm-meijer/nextjs-problem)

Here is some information that may be relevant:

pages/index.js

```
import React from "react";
import Menu from "../components/Menu";

function HomePage() {
  return <Menu />;
}

export default HomePage;
```

components/Menu.js

```
import React, { memo, useMemo } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectCategoriesNested } from "../store/selectors";
import { useCategories } from "../hooks";

function Menu(props) {
  const { categories } = props;

  return (
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(categories, undefined, 2)}</pre>
  );
}
const MemoMenu = memo(Menu);
const MenuContainer = props => {
  console.log("MenuContainer start");
  useCategories();
  const categories = useSelector(selectCategoriesNested);
  const newProps = useMemo(
    () => ({
      ...props,
      categories
    }),
    [props, categories]
  );
  console.log("MenuContainer end", categories);
  return <MemoMenu {...newProps} />;
};
export default MenuContainer;
```

store/initStore.js (used by _app.js)

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import thunkMiddleware from "redux-thunk";
import {
  CATEGORIES_LOADING,
  CATEGORIES_LOADING_SUCCEEDED
} from "./actions";

const initState = {
  categories: {
    requested: false,
    data: {}
  }
};

const rootReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  console.log("reducer:", type);
  if (type === CATEGORIES_LOADING) {
    return {
      ...state,
      categories: { ...state.categories, requested: true }
    };
  }
  if (type === CATEGORIES_LOADING_SUCCEEDED) {
    return {
      ...state,
      categories: {
        ...state.categories,
        data: payload.reduce((categories, category) => {
          categories[category.id] = category;
          return categories;
        }, state.categories.data)
      }
    };
  }
  return state;
};

export const initStore = (initialState = initState) => {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware))
  );
};
```

store/selectors.js

```
import { createSelector } from "reselect";

export const selectCategories = state => state.categories;
export const selectCategoriesRequested = createSelector(
  selectCategories,
  categories => categories.requested
);
export const selectCategoriesData = createSelector(
  selectCategories,
  categories =>
    console.log(
      "selector returning:",
      Object.keys(categories.data).length
    ) || categories.data
);

const nestCategories = data => {
  const categories = Object.values(data).map(category => ({
    ...category,
    subCategories: []
  }));
  const rootCategories = categories.filter(
    category => !category.parent
  );
  const categoriesMap = categories.reduce(
    (categories, category) =>
      categories.set(category.id, category),
    new Map()
  );
  categories.forEach(category => {
    if (
      category.parent &&
      category.parent.typeId === "category"
    ) {
      const parent = categoriesMap.get(category.parent.id);
      parent && parent.subCategories.push(category);
    }
  });
  return rootCategories;
};

// the following does not re render menu when categories
//  are loaded
export const selectCategoriesNested = createSelector(
  selectCategoriesData,
  nestCategories
);
// the following works but breaks menu as pure component
// export const selectCategoriesNested = state =>
//   nestCategories(selectCategoriesData(state));
```

hooks.js

```
import { selectCategoriesRequested } from "./store/selectors";
import { loadCategories } from "./store/actions";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export const useCategories = query => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const requested = useSelector(selectCategoriesRequested);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!requested && process.browser) {
      dispatch(loadCategories(query));
    }
  }, [dispatch, query, requested]);
};
```

output of the log:

```
initStore.js:18   reducer: @@INIT
Menu.js:15        MenuContainer start
selectors.js:10   selector returning: 0
Menu.js:25        MenuContainer end []
initStore.js:18   reducer: CATEGORIES_LOADING
selectors.js:10   selector returning: 0
Menu.js:15        MenuContainer start
Menu.js:25        MenuContainer end []
initStore.js:18   reducer: CATEGORIES_LOADING_SUCCEEDED
selectors.js:10   selector returning: 1
```

If I change the selector to:

```
export const selectCategoriesNested = state =>
  nestCategories(selectCategoriesData(state));
```

I get an 2 extra console logs:

```
Menu.js:15    MenuContainer start
Menu.js:25    MenuContainer end [{…}]
```

What I wonder is why the selector is called **before** MenuContainer start but the selector should be called **from** MenuContainer.

**UPDATE**

Added some logs and looks like nextjs is mutating the store in some way. Added [logs](https://github.com/harm-meijer/nextjs-problem/blob/mutate/store/selectors.js#L49-L62) and after `CATEGORIES_LOADING_SUCCEEDED` action the selector logs from `Same []` to `Same ["1"]`. This should not be possible unless data was mutated but I can't see how [my reducer](https://github.com/harm-meijer/nextjs-problem/blob/mutate/store/initStore.js#L25-L36) mutates the data.

I may be wrong but this looks like a bug so I submitted a [bug report](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/10049)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is embarrising but it was me who made the error. The reducer does mutate state.categories.data in the reduce function:

```
payload.reduce((categories, category) => {
  categories[category.id] = category;
  return categories;
}, state.categories.data);
```

I pass `state.categories.data` as the second argument to `payload.reduce` and in the reducer function I mutate it. This reducer function should be:

```
payload.reduce((categories, category) => {
  categories[category.id] = category;
  return categories;
}, {...state.categories.data});
```